Swift Accelerate Sparse Matrix Support for Complex Numbers
Looking at Accelerate documentation regarding sparse matrices. Can only see support for real numbers. Is there support for sparse matrices with complex elements?

FWIW, vDSP has Complex basic arithmetic vector support. But, AFAIK, they have not (yet) tackled sparse matrices of complex numbers. FWIW, the Swift Numerics package (with Complex type) contemplates BLAS/LAPACK support in the future, but not yet, as I understand it.
